# TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000001C1939EBE90>>

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I try add the product to wishlist it gives me above error, It still saves the object to model

```
def plus_wishlist(reques):
    if request.method == "GET":
        prod_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
        ruser = request.user
        wishlist = Wishlist.objects.create(user=ruser, product=product)
        wishlist.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Added to Wishlist.'})
```

Also when i try to use

```
 ruser=request.user.id
```

**ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Wishlist.user" must be a "User" instance.**

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
        user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Issue is Solved!!**

```
ruser = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.user.id)
```

I dont know if there was login error or what, after getting same error I cleared localhost url and it took me to login page after login there was no issue

Answer (score 0):

Limit views to a view to authenticated users with the [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def plus_wishlist(reques):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prod_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
        product = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
        ruser = request.user
        wishlist = Wishlist.objects.create(user=ruser, product=product)
        wishlist.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Added to Wishlist.'})
```

We can also boost efficiency with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def plus_wishlist(reques):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prod_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
        wishlist = Wishlist.objects.create(
            user_id=request.user.id,
            product_id=prod_id
        )
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Added to Wishlist.'})
```

That being said, you can **not** add an item to a `Wishlist` with a **GET** request: GET requests should have no side-effects. Adding something to a `Wishlist` thus should be done with a POST request.

Comment: I have used Ajax for the request so thats why i used get method Also by adding decorator problem is still there

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar: that does not matter: A GET request is supposed to be safe, cacheable and idempotent. So an nginx server, might think since it is safe, it can use a cache, or the browser. Or a crawler might see the link in the source and make a GET request.

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar: is the `user` field in your `Wishlist` a `ForeignKey` to the user model?

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar: see the HTTP specs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods safe means that there is no state-change. A GET request thus should not add something to a wishlist, remove an entry, log in a person, etc. This is for example why Django does not do cross-site request forgery validation on a GET request, but does on a POST request.

Comment: I got my issue solved by adding this: 

ruser = get_object_or_404(User,id=request.user.id)

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar: do you use a custom user model?

Comment: I used inbuild User model from usercreation form

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar: what if you use `user_id=request.user.id`, as in the bottom code sample. This prevents a useless database query.

Comment: @ShreyashMaskar you definitely can make a POST request (or ones with other methods) using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not authenticated, then Django will return `Anonymous` user when you got the `user` using `request.user`. That instance doesn't have an `id` attribute. You should be sure the user is authenticated before of creating products. Now, the following issue: `It still saves the object to model`, I think that your `Wishlist` model allows setting a null value to the `user` property.